# Simple Trivia Game Comparison

Tags: java

The output of this program always goes to wrong answer. I was wondering how I can compare the user input to the getAnswer() method. I'm fairly new with Java. Any general tips would be great.

Trivia Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Trivia
{
 private String question;
 private String answer;

 public void setQuestion(String question)
{
 this.question = question;
}
 public void setAnswer(String answer)
{
 this.answer = answer;
}
 public String getQuestion()
{
 return question;
}
 public String getAnswer()
{
 return answer;
}
}
```

Main Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriviaTest extends Trivia
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

TriviaTest t1 = new TriviaTest();
TriviaTest t2 = new TriviaTest();
t1.setQuestion("What is the longest river? ");
t1.setAnswer("The Amazon River");
t2.setQuestion("What is the capital of Spain?");
t2.setAnswer("Madrid");
System.out.println(t1.getQuestion());

String a = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
String b = t1.getAnswer();
if(b.equals(a))
{
  System.out.println(" Yes! Correct! ");
}

else
{
  System.out.println(" BZZZZZZ! Wrong answer!");
}
}
}
```

Comment: debug the value of `a`  `System.out.println(a);`

Comment: Please ask a specific question and clearly define the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your actual answer has uppercase and lowercase letters but the value you compare against has been converted to all lower case. `keyboard.next().toLowerCase()`.

A case insensitive compare is what you really want for a trivia game like this. Either convert the stored answer to lowercase as well or store the mixed case answer and do a case insensitive compare (`String.equalsIgnoreCase()`) with the user input .

Note1: step 1 of basic debugging: `System.out.println("a=" + a + ", ans=" +  t1.getAnswer());` would have solved this.

Note2: A better solution would be adding `boolean checkAnswer(String answer)` to the `Trivia` class instead of sticking that important logic in `main`.